# Terraform plan got "missing provider" error after adding a data block

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

This is the module tree I have.

```
Makefile
config
----backend.tfvars
----variables.tfvars
example
    complete
    ----fixtures.us-west-2.tfvars
    ----main.tf
    ----variables.tf
    ----versions.tf
main.tf
outputs.tf
variables.tf
```

I tested in example/complete with aws-vault command like this:

```
aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform init
aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform plan -out=tfplan --var-file=fixtures.us-west-2.tfvars
aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform apply --auto-approve tfplan
aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform plan -out=tfplan --var-file=fixtures.us-west-2.tfvars -destroy
aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform destroy --auto-approve --var-file=fixtures.us-west-2.tfvars
```

There's no problem before. Lately I added a data block for customized policy. Then I received "Error: missing provider provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"]" error, cannot move forward of the test as mentioned above.

```
% aws-vault exec admin-role --region=us-west-2 -- terraform plan -out=tfplan --var-file=fixtures.us-west-2.tfvars
Warning: parent_profile is deprecated, please use include_profile instead in your AWS config

Error: missing provider provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"]
```

My example/complete/main.tf is as simple as below:

```
module "regular_bucket" {
  source = "../../../../root-modules/s3_bucket"

  allow_access_from_another_account = var.allow_access_from_another_account
  allowed_writers                   = var.allowed_writers
  ...
```

This called root-modules/s3_bucket/main.tf, the only additional change is the followings:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "home"
}

data "aws_region" "home" {
  provider = aws.home
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "another_account" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = var.allowed_writers
    }
```

.....

Is it something wrong for me to add the data block to prohibit me from testing (terraform plan or further)?
This is the policy resource block I modified. (just the policy line)

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "regular_bucket" {
      count = local.associate_bucket_policy ? 1 : 0
    
      bucket = aws_s3_bucket.private_access.id
      policy = var.allow_access_from_another_account ? ....
    
        data.aws_iam_policy_document.another_account.json :
        data.aws_iam_policy_document.regular_bucket.0.json
```

versions.tf looks like the following:

```
terraform {
  required_version = " >= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    aws = { 
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.74.1"
    }   
    random = { 
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~> 3.1.0"
    }   
    local = { 
      source  = "hashicorp/local"
      version = ">= 1.3"
    }   
    null = { 
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }   
  }
}
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't need to define the aliased provider in the child module. Add that block to the root module and retry.

Comment: uh, I checked the original code.  This modules has 9 other places using "provider = aws.home", provided it declared on top.  I am hesitating to remove/replace it, while the whole company is using this modules. Wonder if I should remove aws from required_providers in versions.tf